# Are these Linear and Time Invariant Systems?

Tags: linear-systems, homework, theory

We were given the above systems and we were asked to tell whether they are linear (or not) and time invariant(or not).

1. $y(m,n)=x(m,n)+c,\quad c>0$
2. $ y(m,n)=x(m,n)+x(m,-n)$
3. $y(m,n)=x(m,n+m)$
4. $y(m,n)=x(m,n) + y(m-a,n-b)$

Although I know the theory for the signal to be linear and time invariant I have trouble applying it. Can  any of you explain one of the above so I can continue on my own for the rest of them? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi, welcome to DSP SE. What did you do so far? Where are you stuck? Did you do some searching on the website? There is already many answers to such questions.

Comment: Thanks for editing my question, actually i have problem proving all these without having the analytic form of the signal x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the system described in problem 1 is non-linear and time invariant. A linear system cannot have a constant term(or a term independent of input/output).
Here is the proof of it's non-linearity: 
Let y1 and x1 be a set of the o/p and i/p respectively 
y1(m,n)=x1(m,n)+c
Similarly, let y2 and x2 be another such set
y2(m,n)=x2(m,n)+c
Now, let x(m,n)=x1(m,n)+x2(m,n)......(1)
For the system to be linear, when x(m,n)[which is a sum of two signals] is given as input, the output should be a sum of the individual outputs. Let's check:
y(m,n)=x(m,n)+c
from (1), we can write
y(m,n)=x1(m,n)+x2(m,n)+c which is not equal to y1(m,n)+y2(m,n). Hence proved.
The time invariance property is quite straight forward to prove.